# Angular: possible to force recognition of model modifications made outside of $apply()?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

According to the Angular guide on scopes,

> Only model modifications which execute inside the $apply method will
>   be properly accounted for by Angular.

We have quite a few legacy formatting tools for our forum post editor that make changes to a textarea; they operate entirely outside of angular. Now we would like to bind the textarea to an angular model. If the formatting tool used to make the last change made to the textarea, angular does not update the model. Of course, if you were to click a button to add, say, bold to some text, *then* add some additional text, all changes would be recognized.

Short of rewriting all of our tools, is there any way we could force angular to recognize the changes made to the textarea by the formatting tool after, say, one of the formatting tool buttons is clicked?

Comment: Have you tried calling `$rootScope.$apply()` (not the `.$apply(function(){...})` variant) after doing the modifications?

Comment: Not yet--let me try that... Doesn't seem to do it.

Comment: worst cast: append and remove a space to trigger angular change detection...

Comment: dandavis: that's really worst case. :) And even if I wanted to do that, I'm not sure how I would append and remove the space in a way that angular would recognize the change AND retain the previous changes that it did not recognize.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the 3rd party formatting tool has some sort of callback after it has updated the text area you could do something like:

```
angular.element('#myTextArea').scope().$apply();
```

This will retrieve the scope associated with your textarea and fire off a digest cycle in angular.

Comment: The formatting tool I'm using does not have a callback, but I put one in place to try what you've suggested. It didn't appear to work.

Comment: Going to need more information than "It didn't appear to work" to help you.